# Go: read block of lines in a zip file

Tags: go, zip

I need to read a block of n lines in a zip files quickly as possible.

I'm beginer in Go. For bash lovers, I want to do the same as (to get a block of 500 lines between lines 199500 and 200000):

```
time query=$(zcat fake_contacts_200k.zip | sed '199500,200000!d')

real    0m0.106s
user    0m0.119s
sys 0m0.013s
```

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried something? StackOverflow isn't a __write-code-for-me__ service.

Answer (score 2):

1. Import [`archive/zip`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/).
2. Open and read the archive file
   [as shown in the example right there in the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#example_Reader).

   - Note that in order to mimic the behaviour of `zcat` you have to
     first check the length of the `File` field of the `zip.ReadCloser`
     instance returned by a call to `zip.OpenReader`,
     and fail if it is not equal to 1 — that is, there is no files in the
     archive or there are two or more files in it¹.
   - Note that you have to check the error value
     returned by a call to `zip.OpenReader` for being equal to `zip.ErrFormat`,
     and if it's equal, you have to:

     - Close the returned `zip.ReadCloser`.
     - Try to reinterpret the file as being `gzip`-formatted (step 4).
3. Take the first (and sole) `File` member and
   call [`Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#File.Open) on it.

   You can then read the file's contents from the returned `io.ReaderCloser`.

   After reading, you need to call `Close()` on that instance and then
   close the zip file as well. That's all. ∎
4. If step (2) failed because the file did not have the zip format,
   you'd test whether it's gzip-formatted.

   In order to do this, you do basically the same steps using the
   [`compress/gzip`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip) package.

   Note that contrary to the zip format, gzip does not provide *file archival* — it's merely a compressor, so there's no meta information on any files in the gzip stream, just the compressed data.
   (This fact is underlined by the difference in the names of the packages.)

   If an attempt to opening the same file as a gzip archive returns
   the `gzip.ErrHeader` error, you bail out, otherwise you read the data
   after which you close the reader. That's all. ∎

To process just the specific lines from the decompressed file,
you'd need to

1. Skip the lines before the first one to process.
2. Process the lines until, and including the last one to process.
3. Stop processing.

To interpret the data read from an `io.Reader` or `io.ReadCloser`,
it's best to use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) —
see the "Example (Lines)" there.

P.S.

Please read thoroughly [this essay](https://whathaveyoutried.com)
to try to make your next question better that this one.

---

¹ You might as well read all the files and interpret their contents
as a contiguous stream — that would deviate from the behaviour of `zcat`
but that might be better. It really depends on your data.